# How to create ContextMenu with no border in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, border, contextmenu

How to create ContextMenu with no border in C# (winform)?

The question is quite straight forward, I just only want to remove the border of ContextMenu. 
The ContextMenu here is System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu.

If the only solution is to inherit ContextMenu and override DrawItem, there's no worse pain.

Any suggestion?

Comment: C# does not have context menus. You'll have to specify a GUI lib.

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu, isn't it?

Comment: @Paul It's in WPF as well, that's why you need to specify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WPF then you can set the border thickness to 0

```
<ContextMenu BorderThickness="0">
```

Comment: @Oskar, I have rephrased my words :)

Comment: bad news that i'm using winform, got a solution?